# Paypal Transaction search using tokens

Tags: java, paypal

Paypal provides option of Permissions Service which let application to contact API using the tokens it provides. I got the token. But how to use the token for Transaction search.

I am able to go Transaction search by the link they have provided : [example](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_TransactionSearch). but i want to do it using the tokens i got using the following process : [token procedure](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_PermissionsUsing)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it using the example : [link](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_PermissionsUsing)